# Aggregating org files in a single buffer, optionally grouping by common headings. Which building blocks could be used in emacs?

Tags: org-mode, buffers

If possible, what APIs or emacs features would be suitable to implement a "view" ("computed") buffer that would:

- allow aggregating content from multiple buffers in a single buffer
- optionally allow changes to this view-buffer to be reflected back to the respective source files

Example use case:

- Daily org journal uses a template with a few headings. Many different files of similar structure accumulate over time (each day).
- I'd like to have a buffer where the daily entries are grouped in a single view, that optionally has edit capabilities.

Eg:

```
---- day-X.org
* Things to do
Ax
Bx
* Reminders
Cx
Dx

---- day-Y.org
* Things to do
Ay
By
* Reminders
Cy
Dy
```

The feature described above would allow displaying a computed buffer that would look like:

```
----- aggregate view buffer
* Things to do
[day X]
Ax
Bx

[day Y]
Ay
By

* Reminders
[day X]
Cx
Dx

[day Y]
Cy
Dy
```

Optional: Editing Cy in the aggregate buffer would reflect changes to day-Y.org.

Comment: I would accumulate everything in a single datetree file and use agendas to organize what I want to see out of them (e.g. today's journal entries).

Answer (score 1):

You could learn all of that by reading the code for `occur-edit` mode.